# Why doesn't my Appcompat be resolved?

Tags: android, xml

**THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED. THANKS. THE METHOD IS IN THE COMMENTS**

**I don't know whether this is a problem or not but since it's RED I assume so.**

In my other java and xml files my Appcompat is highlighted in red. I think something is wrong but I can't pinpoint it.  Please Help?

My Screen Shot of styles.xml file
[image]

**My build.gradle Code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hk.ust.cse.comp107x.shootinggame"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean / rebuild ?

Comment: Yes, as suggested I cleaned and re-builded my project. Alas! to no avail. The RED code still remains. I don't even know why it's red. :(

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Caches/restart?

Comment: @Peter I just did that about 2 minutes before your comment and Lo! it worked. Nevertheless,Thanks a lot. Though I don't understand why it worked...